# Editing a file with non-ascii characters

Tags: html, text, editing, non-ascii-characters

I have a text file containing a lot (about 300) entries of the following form:

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="message_header">
        <span class="user">??????</span>
        <span class="meta">Friday, November 11, 2016 at 9:45am    UTC+02</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>??????????</p>
```

where ?????? is text in greek.
How can I reverse the entries in the file so that the last entry becomes first etc?
I have tried to make a C++ program but I'm having a big trouble with non ascii characters.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Python 3 is great for Unicode. Is your file posted somewhere?